# Overwrite/Join MySQL table with another table on select

Tags: mysql, join, null, left-join, zero

I have two product tables. Table A is the "default" table (comes from data feed is automatically updated weekly). Table B is used to manually overwrite the values in Table A and has the same columns as Table plus a few more. Both tables always have the same UniqueID column.

I need a select statement that pulls all the values from A and all the values from B, with B overwriting the values from A UNLESS the value from B is null, = to 0 or equal to 0.00 (column set to integer with 2 decimal points and been filled with "0").

I tried using a LEFT JOIN but am having trouble with the null and "0" values.

I am using the data in php and can deal with it when I only need to pull in 1 row. I query for each, extract the assoc array for A, filter the B array and then extract it. But that process becomes very clunky when start to pull in 20-200 rows.

Table A has about 400,000 rows and can't see B getting over 10,000-20,000.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Here is the code I got to work.

`SELECT a.UniqueId,
        IF(b.Color, b.Color, a.Color) as Color,
    IF(b.Price1 = 0, a.Price1, b.Price1) as Price1, 
    b.SPrice1
    FROM productdata a LEFT JOIN product_overrides b ON a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID  WHERE a.UniqueID =  $prod";`

UPDATE 2: So simple is better. IF() addresses both null and zero.

IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)

If expr1 is TRUE (**expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL**) then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

`SELECT a.UniqueId,
        IF(b.Color, b.Color, a.Color) as Color,
    IF(b.Price1, b.Price1, a.Price1) as Price1, 
    b.SPrice1
    FROM productdata a LEFT JOIN product_overrides b ON a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID  WHERE a.UniqueID =  $prod";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this aught to cover all your scenarios:

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(b.nullablefield, a.nullablefield) as nullablefield,
   IF(b.intfield = 0, a.intfield, b.intfield) as intfield,
   IF(b.floatfield = 0, a.floatfield, b.floatfield) as floatfield,
   ... etc ...
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID
```

Comment: SELECT UniqueID, COALESCE(b.Price1, a.Price1) as Price1, FROM productdata a LEFT JOIN product_overrides b ON a.UniqueID = b.UniqueID WHERE UniqueID = "5676544";

gets me a 1064 syntax. If I swap * for COALESCE it works.

Comment: @EricImprint - Looks like you have an extra comma after `Price1`